# iphone iOS5 audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying not called screen lock?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, avaudioplayer, sleep

I have a series of audio files which I want to play in sequence.  I setup audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate method to start the next file in the sequence.  This works with no problem if I turn off screen lock or if I run it on the emulator or on an iOS4 device.  However, when I run it on a disconnected device, iOS5, screen locked, it stops after the first track.  Is there some way to start a new sound track after the screen lock has come on?

Here is my basic code

```
// Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

// Use this code instead to allow the app sound to continue to play when the screen is locked.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
AudioSessionSetProperty ( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                         sizeof (doSetProperty),
                         &doSetProperty
                         );

// Registers the audio route change listener callback function
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
                                 kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
                                 audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
                                 self
                                 );

// Activates the audio session.

NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"m4a"];  
    float vol = [appSoundPlayer volume];

    AVAudioPlayer * newAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];  
    self.appSoundPlayer = newAudio; // automatically retain audio and dealloc old file if new file is loaded

    [newAudio release]; // release the audio safely

    appSoundPlayer.delegate = self; 
    [appSoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [appSoundPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
    [appSoundPlayer play];
    [appSoundPlayer setVolume:vol];
    [progTime setProgress:0];
}


   - (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) lappSoundPlayer successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    //... code here to select nex sound track
                    [lappSoundPlayer play];
    }
```

I have already made it so the app continues to play the current track even when screen lock comes on, I just can't get it to start up the next track.

Note: I have verified that this was working in iOS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set up an audio session category, specifically `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW3)?

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];    
NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
```

If that doesn't work, another thing to try, according to user ascanio in [this message](https://devforums.apple.com/message/264397) in the Apple dev forums, is to set your app up to listen for remote control events:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Comment: Yes to the first question.  The second looks possible, I will check into that -- thanks!

Comment: In preliminary testing the second solution is working, I will award the well deserved bounty after I have completed my testing.

Comment: Hope it does work!  But I feel guilty about accepting a bounty since I just stumbled across your question and saw no one had answered it.

Comment: Looks great, I'm so happy somebody finally answered -- no need for guilt.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me... I am trying to have a sound continue after lock screen as well but when I add this code the lock screen simply stops my app from running in iOS5.. did you register something else to allow audio?

Comment: Yes, you also have to tell iOS that you want to run in the background.  Add `UIBackgroundModes` to your Info.plist and set the value to `audio`.  Cf. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24